# Why Does Unsupported exception is thrown when i am trying below code?

Tags: java, list

```
public void process(List<? extends Student> list) {
  List<Student> list = (List<Student>) items;
  for (Student student : list) {
    if (student.getAge > 60) {
      list.remove(student);
    }
  }
}
```

The above code throws unsupportedOperation Exception at list.remove(student) line. is it because of "List<? extends Student> list" in method parameters ?

Comment: No, it's because you're passing in a `List` which doesn't support the `remove` operation. Besides this, if you didn't get the `UnsupportedOperationException`, you'd likely get a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: when you are inside a boucle of iterator you can remove an element of the list

Answer (score 3):

> is it because of "List<? extends Student> list" in method parameters ?

No.

It's because you're passing in a `List` which doesn't support the `remove` operation. [It's an optional operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-).

Besides this, if you didn't get the `UnsupportedOperationException`, you'd likely get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, because you're removing from a `List` that you're iterating.

An easier, correct way (on a `List` which supports removal) would be:

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.getAge() > 60);
```

If you need to do something with the item you're removing, use an `Iterator`:

```
Iterator<? extends Student> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  Student s = it.next();
  if (s.getAge() > 60) {
    s.remove();
    // Do whatever.
  }
}
```

However, be aware that removal from the middle of lists (e.g. `ArrayList`) in a loop is inefficient.

Comment: I can definitely use removeIf. But i need to log the the item that is removed from the list as below. Thats why i opted for for loop.

 if(student.getAge  > 60){


        list.remove(student); 
lof.info("student removed={}", student);



}

Comment: But line 1 gives me error. saying that required Iterator<Student>. provided Iterator<capture of ? extends Student>

Answer (score 0):

AndyTurner already explained your problem, I just want to add.
You can use Stream API to get the removed student list and then log them

```
List<Student> removedStudent = list.stream()
                                   .filter(s -> s.getAge() > 60)
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then remove from the list

```
list.removeIf(s -> s.getAge() > 60);
```

You can use `removeAll` also if you override equals method

```
list.removeAll(removedStudent);
```

*Note:* Here `getAge` is may be field, use just `age` or with a getter of field like `getAge()`